# 401 unauthorized error when testing endpoint in Azure API

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions, azure-api-management, unauthorized

I'm working on azure to make a cloud service for my summer job. I wanted to make an API, calling my database, and it is supposed to be OPEN, meaning if we open a web browser and write the endpoint link, we get the result without a problem. I made a C# azure function as a template a HTTP trigger with Open API.

Locally it works, but when I push it on azure cloud, and when I test it in API management, I get a **401 unauthorized error**, no matter the endpoints. I tried uncheck the "require subscription" box, still not working, I tried deleting the API ressource, uncheck the box and then publish, still nothing.

How can I fix it? I just want to make my API fully open without any unauthorization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have very much experience with API Management. But in order to call an endpoint from API Management you'll have to add the following Header to your request:

```
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key
```

The value of this key can be found in the Azure Portal under your API Management resource.

[image: APIM Azure]

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately, even with the subscription key, it still says 401 unauthorized...

Comment: @ToTTToR you might wanna check Authorization settings of your Azure Function.

Comment: Ok so I changed the authorization level in the function to anonymous and that solved it. I just find it weird that locally I don't need any subscription key or anything, even with the Authorization level as function. Thank you!